# Cookie problem with node/apollo/express server after deploying to Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, next.js, apollo-server

I'm building node js server with apollo and front end with next.js/apollo client. My problem is that on localhost everything is works as it must be, but after deploying to Heroku cookies not set. I'm getting the data from server and redirects me to the home page, but after page reload it redirects me to login page again.

This is apollo server code

```
import cors from 'cors'
import Redis from 'ioredis'
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
import express from 'express'
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
import session from 'express-session'
import connectRedis from 'connect-redis'
import { ApolloServer } from 'apollo-server-express'

import typeDefs from './schema'
import resolvers from './resolvers'

dotenv.config({
  path: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`,
})

const port = process.env.PORT || 4000
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'

const RedisStore = connectRedis(session)

const startServer = async () => {
  await mongoose
    .connect(process.env.DB_URL, { useNewUrlParser: true })
    .then(() => console.log(`  MongoDB Connected...`))
    .catch(err => console.log(`❌  MongoDB Connection error: ${err}`))

  const app = express()

  const server = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
    playground: !dev
      ? false
      : {
          settings: {
            'request.credentials': 'include',
          },
        },
    context: ({ req, res }) => ({ req, res }),
  })

  app.disable('x-powered-by')
  app.set('trust proxy', 1)

  app.use(
    cors({
      credentials: true,
      origin:
        process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
          ? process.env.FRONT_END_URL
          : 'http://localhost:3000',
    }),
  )

  app.use((req, _, next) => {
    const authorization = req.headers.authorization

    if (authorization) {
      try {
        const cid = authorization.split(' ')[1]
        req.headers.cookie = `cid=${cid}`
        console.log(cid)
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
    }

    return next()
  })

  app.use(
    session({
      store: new RedisStore({
        host: process.env.REDIS_HOST,
        port: process.env.REDIS_PORT,
        pass: process.env.REDIS_PASS,
      }),
      name: process.env.SESS_NAME,
      secret: process.env.SESS_SECRET,
      saveUninitialized: false,
      resave: false,
      cookie: {
        httpOnly: true,
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7, // 7 days
        secure: false,
      },
    }),
  )

  server.applyMiddleware({ app, cors: false })

  app.listen({ port }, () =>
    console.log(
      `  Server ready at http://localhost:${port}${server.graphqlPath}`,
    ),
  )
}

startServer()
```

and this is the resolvers

```
import gravatar from 'gravatar'
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt'

import { User } from '../models'
import { isAuthenticated, signOut } from '../auth'
import { loginSchema, registerSchema } from '../utils'

export default {
  Query: {
    users: (parent, args, { req }, info) => {
      isAuthenticated(req)

      return User.find({})
    },
    user: (parent, { id }, context, info) => {
      isAuthenticated(req)

      return User.findById(id)
    },
    me: (parent, args, { req }, info) => {
      isAuthenticated(req)

      return User.findById(req.session.userId)
    },
  },
  Mutation: {
    signUp: async (parent, args, { req }, info) => {
      // isAuthenticated(req)

      args.email = args.email.toLowerCase()

      try {
        await registerSchema.validate(args, { abortEarly: false })
      } catch (err) {
        return err
      }

      args.avatar = await gravatar.url(
        args.email,
        {
          protocol: 'https',
          s: '200', // Size
          r: 'pg', // Rating
          d: 'mm', // Default
        },
        true,
      )

      args.password = await bcrypt.hash(args.password, 12)
      const user = await User.create(args)

      req.session.userId = user.id

      return user
    },
    signIn: async (parent, args, { req }, info) => {
      // isAuthenticated(req)

      const { email, password } = args

      try {
        await loginSchema.validate(args, { abortEarly: false })
      } catch (err) {
        return err
      }

      const user = await User.findOne({ email })

      if (!user || !(await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password))) {
        throw new Error('Incorrect email or password. Please try again.')
      }

      req.session.userId = user.id

      return user
    },
    signOut: (parent, args, { req, res }, info) => {
      return signOut(req, res)
    },
  },
}
```

and here is apollo client on front end (I'm using with-apollo-auth example from next.js)

```
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client'
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory'
import { createHttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http'
import { setContext } from 'apollo-link-context'
import fetch from 'isomorphic-unfetch'

let apolloClient = null

if (!process.browser) {
  global.fetch = fetch
}

function create(initialState, { getToken }) {
  const httpLink = createHttpLink({
    uri:
      process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
        ? 'http://localhost:4000/graphql'
        : process.env.BACK_END_URL,
    credentials: 'include',
  })

  const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
    const token = getToken()
    return {
      headers: {
        ...headers,
        authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : '',
      },
    }
  })

  return new ApolloClient({
    connectToDevTools: process.browser,
    ssrMode: !process.browser,
    link: authLink.concat(httpLink),
    cache: new InMemoryCache().restore(initialState || {}),
  })
}

export default function initApollo(initialState, options) {
  if (!process.browser) {
    return create(initialState, options)
  }

  if (!apolloClient) {
    apolloClient = create(initialState, options)
  }

  return apolloClient
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it may be related to heroku cookie size limit but not sure

Comment: I'm thinking that something related with this https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cookies-and-herokuapp-com

Comment: did you find a solution? @ByurhanBeyzat

Comment: I'dont remember what exactly was my problem but there is a issue with a lot of answers https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/4190

I hope you find your solution